# How can I disable/enable form submit in an ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I'm trying first disabling form submission before the request starts and then on success enable again the form submit

this is my code:

```
$.ajax({
 beforeSend:function(){
//disable form
            $('form').on('submit',function(){
               return false;
            });
},
success:function(){
            //enable form
            $('form').on('submit',function(){
               return true;
            });
},
complete:function(){
            //enable form
            $('form').on('submit',function(){
               return true;
            });
,
});
```

it seems not working on success and complete, the form is disabled but not enabled then.

I'm using latest jQuery version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Better use different strategy: Set a global variable to decide whether or not to submit the form. Then check it while submitting the form.

```
var canSubmit = 1;

$.ajax({
 beforeSend:function(){
   //disable form
   canSubmit = 0;
},
success:function(){
   //enable form
   canSubmit = 1;
},
complete:function(){
   //disable form
   canSubmit = 1;
});

$('form').on('submit',function() {
   if (!canSubmit) {
      return false;
   }
});
```

Comment: don't know if it's the best practice, but this fixed at all, thanks !

Answer (score 1):

jQuery events normally support multiple handlers so you would need to turn the previous event handlers [off](http://api.jquery.com/off/) before attaching a new one.

To use `off` you need to keep a reference to your handler e.g.

```
var myForm = $("form"),
    enableSubmit = function(event) { return true; },
    disableSubmit = function(event) { return false; },
    ajaxCompleteHandler = function() {
        myForm.off(disableSubmit);
        myForm.on(enableSubmit);
    };

myForm.on(enableSubmit);

$.ajax({
    beforeSend: function() {
        myForm.off(enableSubmit);
        myForm.on(disableSubmit);
    },
    success: ajaxCompleteHandler,
    error: ajaxCompleteHandler,
    complete: ajaxCompleteHandler //you might get away with just this as I believe it's called for success and failure
});
```

Alternatively you could just disable the submit button `($("mybutton").prop("disabled", true)`)which should be more intuitive to the user.

Comment: disabling only the button will cause that if i push enter key an a form input the form will be submitted anyway :P

Comment: do you have an example please for the off() ?

Comment: True, using a flag as recommended elsewhere probably better than changing event handlers. Also it's worth re-enabling submit in the ajax error event handler.

Comment: Added example of using 'off'

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing a return false in **beforeSend** try this

```
$('form').on('submit',function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   return false;
});
```

Comment: yes but what to do then in success and complete? the beforeSend seems to work, the problems seems on success and complete

Comment: Did you try it? Your return true should be just fine =S.

Answer (score 0):

Once you return false on the submit button,it is obvious that you cannot again invoke submit operation, because the form is not now able to submit info.

The another solution is that use onclick function,like below :

Javascript file

```
function savecustomquestion(){
$.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url : 'customquestion.php',
        data:{tablename:$('#productname').val(),name:$('#uname').val(),email_address:$('#email').val(),voucher_code:$('#voucher_code').val(),question:$('#customquestion').val()},
        success: function(response){
            console.log("yes");
        },
        error : function(response){
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
```

}

HTML code

```
<button type="button" id="customquestionbutton" class="span2" onclick="savecustomquestion()">Verstuur</button>
```

PHP code

```
mysql_select_db('mydatabase',$connect);

if(!isset($_POST['voucher_code'])){
    $voucher_code   = "";
}
else{
    $voucher_code   = $_POST['voucher_code'];
}
$email_address = $_POST['email_address'];
$name          = $_POST['name'];
$question      = $_POST['question'];
$tablename     = $_POST['tablename'];

mysql_query("insert into customquestion (voucher_code,email_address,name,question)    VALUES('$voucher_code','$email_address','$name','$question') ");
```